# I try bank accounts in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to this programming and together with an AI and tried to create a bank account attempt with login and, with 3 users and their respective password, where you can deposit and withdraw, with the rule of not exceeding the sum of 990 and not less than 10, the problem is that it does not pass the login,  It goes blank, could someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bank Account Simulation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bank Account Simulation</h1>

    <div id="login">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Username: <input type="text" id="username"></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" id="password"></p>
        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </div>

    <div id="account1" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Account 1</h2>
        <p>Balance: <span id="balance1"></span></p>
        <button onclick="deposit1()">Deposit</button>
        <button onclick="withdraw1()">Withdraw</button>
    </div>

    <div id="account2" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Account 2</h2>
        <p>Balance: <span id="balance2"></span></p>
        <button onclick="deposit2()">Deposit</button>
        <button onclick="withdraw2()">Withdraw</button>
    </div>

    <div id="account3" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Account 3</h2>
        <p>Balance: <span id="balance3"></span></p>
        <button onclick="deposit3()">Deposit</button>
        <button onclick="withdraw3()">Withdraw</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let account1 = {
            balance: 100
        };
        let account2 = {
            balance: 200
        };
        let account3 = {
            balance: 300
        };

        let users = {
            "usuario1": "contraseña1",
            "usuario2": "contraseña2",
            "usuario3": "contraseña3"
        };

        function showBalance1() {
            document.getElementById("balance1").innerHTML = account1.balance;
        }
        function showBalance2() {
            document.getElementById("balance2").innerHTML = account2.balance;
        }
        function showBalance3() {
            document.getElementById("balance3").innerHTML = account3.balance;
        }

        function deposit1() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a depositar:");
            account1.balance += parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account1);
            showBalance1();
        }
        function deposit2() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a depositar:");
            account2.balance += parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account2);
            showBalance2();
        }
        function deposit3() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a depositar:");
            account3.balance += parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account3);
            showBalance3();
        }

        function withdraw1() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a retirar:");
            account1.balance -= parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account1);
            showBalance1();
        }
        function withdraw2() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a retirar:");
            account2.balance -= parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account2);
            showBalance2();
        }
        function withdraw3() {
            let amount = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad a retirar:");
            account3.balance -= parseInt(amount);
            validateBalance(account3);
            showBalance3();
        }

         function validateBalance(account) {
             if (account.balance > 990) {
                 account.balance = 990;
                 alert("La cuenta no puede tener más de $990.");
             }
             if (account.balance < 10) {
                 account.balance = 10;
                 alert("La cuenta no puede tener menos de $10.");
             }
         }

         function login() {
             let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
             let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

             if (users[username] == password) {
                 document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
             } else {
                 alert("Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
             }
         }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code to change the `display` property of any of these elements

```html
<div id="account1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="account2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="account3" style="display:none;"></div>
```

so they remain hidden.

You need to add something like

```js
document.getElementById("account1").style.display = "";
```

after a successful login.

---

There is a lot of redundant code here. You are better off creating elements and writing functions that can be reused.

Here is a simple example:

```js
let activeAccount = ""
let accounts = {
  "user1": {
    password: "pw1",
    balance: 100
  },
  "user2": {
    password: "pw2",
    balance: 200
  },
  "usuario1": {
    password: "contraseña1",
    balance: 50
  },
  "usuario2": {
    password: "contraseña2",
    balance: 100
  },
  "usuario3": {
    password: "contraseña3",
    balance: 150
  }
};

const renderBalance = () => {
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = accounts[activeAccount].balance;
};

const destroyBalance = () => {
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = "";
};

const showAccount = () => {
  renderBalance();
  document.getElementById("account-name").innerHTML = `Account of ${activeAccount}`;
  document.getElementById("account").style.display = "";
};

const hideAccount = () => {
  destroyBalance()
  document.getElementById("account-name").innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementById("account").style.display = "none";
};

const adjustBalance = (type, msg) => {
  const input = parseInt(prompt(msg));

  if (input === null)
    return;

  if (isNaN(input))
    return alert("Invalid amount.");

  const newBalance = accounts[activeAccount].balance + (type * Math.abs(input));

  if (newBalance < 0)
    return alert("Insufficient funds.");

  accounts[activeAccount].balance = newBalance;

  renderBalance();
};

document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let username = document.getElementById("username");
  let password = document.getElementById("password");

  if (accounts?.[username.value].password === password.value) {
    document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
    activeAccount = username.value;
    username.value = "";
    password.value = "";
    showAccount();
  } else {
    alert("User not found.");
  }
});

document.getElementById("logout-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  hideAccount();
  activeAccount = "";
  document.getElementById("login").style.display = "";
});

document.getElementById("deposit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  adjustBalance(+1, "Enter an amount to deposit.");
});

document.getElementById('withdraw').addEventListener("click", () => {
  adjustBalance(-1, "Enter an amount to withdraw.");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bank Account Simulation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Bank Account Simulation</h1>

  <div id="login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <p>Username: <input type="text" id="username"></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" id="password"></p>
    <button id="login-button">Login</button>
  </div>

  <div id="account" style="display:none;">
    <h2 id="account-name"></h2>
    <p>Balance: <span id="balance"></span></p>
    <button id="deposit">Deposit</button>
    <button id="withdraw">Withdraw</button>
    <button id="logout-button">Logout</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```